# How to use UserControls in an ItemsRepeater for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use a UserControl inside an ItemsRepeater and having issues with it.I am using Prism and the MVVM model

I defined a UserControl in a separate A.xaml file

```
  <UserControl>
  <Grid>
     <Button Background="Grey" Content="{x:Bind AViewModel.text}">
  <Button>
  <Grid>
  <UserControl>
```

The corresponding A.xaml.cs file has the binding to AViewModel which defines the property text

I have another XAML file B.xaml which uses this control defined as follows

```
<Grid>
  <ItemsRepeater ItemSource={"x:Bind BViewModel.ListOfObservableCollection"}>
     <ItemRepeater.Layout>
        <StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
  </ItemRepeater.Layout>
</ItemsRepeater>
</Grid>
```

This XAML file has a corresponding B.XAML.cs file which binds to BViewModel which has the List of Observable collection. I wish to display a vertical list of button which has text from the List of Observation Collection by using UserControl. How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use UserControls in an ItemsRepeater for UWP

You could insert UserControl into ItemsRepeater's `ItemTemplate`. And give  UserControl  DependencyProperty to receive text value.  Please note you need edit `ListOfObservableCollection` content to  `AViewModel` like the following

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Background="Gray" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

- code behind

  ```
   public sealed partial class AControl : UserControl
    {
        public AControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
        }


        public string ButtonContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(AControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    }
  ```

**Usage**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:BViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <muxc:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObservableCollection}">
        <muxc:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:AControl ButtonContent="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </muxc:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
    </muxc:ItemsRepeater>
    <local:AControl ButtonContent="hh" />
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
   
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
     
    }
}
public class AViewModel
{    
    public string Text { get; set; }
   
}
public class BViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AViewModel> ListOfObservableCollection { get; set; }
    public BViewModel()
    {
        ListOfObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<AViewModel>();
        ListOfObservableCollection.Add(new AViewModel { Text = "Test1" });
        ListOfObservableCollection.Add(new AViewModel { Text = "Test1" });
        ListOfObservableCollection.Add(new AViewModel { Text = "Test1" });
        ListOfObservableCollection.Add(new AViewModel { Text = "Test1" });
    }
}
```